# How can I get my local network machines to call local web server by URL?

Tags: web-server, bind, local-area-network, dns-hosting, architecture

I have four computers connected to a single switch - unconnected to the internet.

One of the computers (the large one in the picture) is more powerful than the others and is running Ubuntu, with three live Node.js web servers with different apps on different ports.
The other computers are running Windows.

I want the other three computers to access the web servers by calling a URL, for example

- files.bugsteins   --> 192.168.0.5:3000
- chat.bugsteins    --> 192.168.0.5:3001
- devices.bugsteins  --> 192.168.0.5:3002

What is the best (priority to fastest set up time) way to accomplish this ?

Thus far I have tried Bind9 on the server machine and assigning static IPs and manual hardcoded  DNS on the three client machines but it is not working and as I work on it, I figure I will post this question in case someone has a better way.

[image: Network Architecture]

Comment: What have you tried? What technologies do you think might be in play to get this working?

Comment: Good point. I updated my question

Comment: Hear you can find a way to do this using nginx and local DNS or host file entries. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/multiple-domains-on-different-ports-of-the-same-droplet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best (priority to fastest set up time) way to accomplish this?

Not BIND.

Edit the `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file on each desktop and point those names to 192.168.0.5.

```
192.168.0.5 files.bugsteins 
192.168.0.5 chat.bugsteins
192.168.0.5 devices.bugsteins
```

Add a web listener on port 80 on the server, somehow with your Node.js setup, or a basic webserver install (Lighttpd, NginX, Apache, or heaps of others) serving a static page with a JavaScript in it which looks at the URL and redirects the page to the appropriate port.

Taking from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022636/redirection-based-on-url-javascript something like this (untested):

```
<html>
<head><title>Redirect page</title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

if (window.location.href== "http://files.bugsteins") {
   window.location.href = 'http://files.bugsteins:3000'; 
}

if (window.location.href== "http://chat.bugsteins") {
   window.location.href = 'http://chat.bugsteins:3001'; 
}

if (window.location.href== "http://devices.bugsteins") {
   window.location.href = 'http://devices.bugsteins:3002'; 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would prefer setting up a web server at port 80 on the web server, and then having it proxy the request to the Node.js servers.

Comment: Take a look at Apache's mod_proxy and the directives ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse to redirect inbound http traffic to other ports.  Combined with dnsmasq you have something that should work!

Comment: I think both of the comments go against `best (priority to fastest set up time)` in that configuring a web server proxy will take more time and effort than 'serving a static page'.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler this worked great thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The fastest will be installing the dnsmasq package depending on your Linux distros(Arch/CentOS/RHEL/Ubuntu). Keep all the entries in /etc/hosts on your DNS server (which is using dnsmasq). Point all your workstations/linux hosts to here.

Also, make sure to set forwarders to outside internet DNS server for non-local requests.

For small environments say <100 machines, this is good enough and minimalistic DNS server.

Comment: I mentioned the server machine is running Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean regarding updating the /etc/hosts/ on my Ubuntu machine (which is the server)? Don't I want to do that on my client machines?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Doesn't really matter if it's CentOS/RHEL/ubuntu as long as it's dnsmasq software.

That means your Ubuntu (DNS server) - the one and only DNS server will need to have all these configs below. You don't need to configure any complex zone files like BIND service.

ubuntudnsserver001 (/etc/hosts):
192.168.1.1 ubuntupc001
192.168.1.2 ubuntupc002
192.168.1.3 ubuntupc003
...

Comment: Also, you don't have to configure dnsmasq on your client machines. Just the Ubuntu machine which is your DNS server.

All your workstations will point to your Ubuntu DNS server as normal through /etc/resolv.conf file.

Answer (score -1):

Normally this would be handled with an internal DNS server.  If you do not have one running, you could just add entries to the local host file on each of the 3 client computers.